# How to write trigger in ruby on rails on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, triggers

I want that when new entry insert in Logs model column of another model updated after that.

For this I want to write trigger on insertion but I cant find any helping material how to write trigger in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)? It seems like this is what you are after.

Maybe something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :add_log_entry

  private

  def add_log_entry
    LogModel.create(message: 'post thingy')
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I know the difference between trigger and callbacks? Or they are same thing?

Comment: I would say that they are mote or less the same thing.